# The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini

Tags: uploads, permissions

I'm trying to upload a XML file through Wordpress Importer

It shows this error, no matter what the size of the file is.

Even 10kb file throws up this error.

My php.ini settings were set to 100MB, still no change. Back to defaults, wich is 8MB.

I'm starting to think it's permission related.

Any ideas?

Comment: Who is your host? Tried talking to them? When I have encountered permissions issues w/ WordPress on HostGator, there is a script they run to reset all of the permissions. Usually works pretty well.

Comment: I've talked to them yesterday, they couldn't solve it... They didn't reset the pemissions, but that's just a guess too

Comment: GoDaddy's respose: "Hmm, I'm really not sure why this is happening sir. All of the permissions look correct on your files, the php.ini is working normally"

Comment: Don't forget `post_max_size` should always be *at least* equal to `upload_max_filesize`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the following changes in php.ini file on your server.

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```

If still it's same then update value of memory_limit.

Answer (score 0):

Use `phpinfo()` to verify what the setting is. Some hosts do not allow you to change the PHP settings via php.ini. Some may require that you do it via .htaccess. If when you run `phpinfo()` the value is different than the 100MB you set it to via php.ini then there's a good chance this is the case.

Look through your host's knowledge base or give them a call and they can tell you their preferred method of changing PHP settings. Also, some hosts do not allow you to change certain settings in which case you'll need to request that they make the change. They will be able to tell you this as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: According to phpinfo upload_max_filesize is 100MB

Comment: @user2056484 What is the value of `post_max_size` ?

Comment: 8MB (filling this space to fit the minimum characters to send this message)

Comment: @user2056484 Hmmm... I was thinking if it was lower than 10kB then that would be your problem because as **TheDeadMedic** mentioned above `post_max_size` should at least be the same as `upload_max_filesize`. Where is the php.ini that you changed located? Root? Check to see if you have one in `wp-admin`. This one would override the other and is where you would want to make your changes.